# Design pattern for composition workflows

Tags: design-patterns, workflows, composition

Please bear with me as I find this tricky to articulate exactly what I am after (probably not a good sign..).

I have several services set up which can be combined in a particular order to create workflows. For example, imagine I have the following services:

- 1) HTTP -> File Store (takes a file over HTTP and stores it)
- 2) FTP -> File Store
- 3) File Store-> FTP (takes a file over HTTP and pushes to FTP)
- 4) File Store-> Transformation -> File Store(applies a transformation to a file in File Store).

I might want to combine services to create a particular workflow, for example.

1) -> 4) -> 3)

Or

2) -> 4) -> 3)

And it might be the case that I perform exactly the same operation e.g. in the workflows above, step 4 could be applied on the same item twice, if the same item is sent over HTTP and FTP. I might also want to trigger subworkflows for example:

4) -> 3)

Would be a valid workflow. Is there a  design pattern/known approach to handling these 'cascading' workflows? I would like to avoid duplicate operations where possible but also design workflows in a separate, contained manner. The only thing that comes to mind for me is some sort of composition based approach where workflows are composed of several sub-workflows.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Actor Model: Akka, NServiceBus.

Comment: Hi Den, can you go into more detail about a particular design pattern?

Comment: It's not a design pattern, it's a paradigm. Represent coarse reusable functionality as actors, decouple them by message-based communication, combine as needed. Also I am not sure what is a "workflow" for you - chain of actions or just one action.

Comment: @Alex, Perhaps something like a [state monad](http://blog.jorgenschaefer.de/2013/02/monads-for-normal-programmers-part-2.html) is what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure really whether this will help but in F# you could create a computation expression something like the following,

```
 let workFlow = 
      workflow {
         let! pageContents = ("read url", readHttp "http://www.google.com")
         do! ("write file", writeFile @"c:\temp\google.html" pageContents)
      } |> runWorkflow
```

This can be built from the following functions

```
 let runStage (name, f:Async<'a>) = 
     async {
         try
             do printfn "Running %s" name
             let! result = f
             return Choice1Of2(result)
          with e ->
             printfn "Stage %s failed %A" name e
             return Choice2Of2 e
     }

 type WorkflowBuilder() = 
     member x.Bind((name,curr), next:('a -> Async<'b>)) = 
             async { 
                     let! result = runStage (name, curr)
                     match result with
                     | Choice1Of2(r) -> return! next(r)
                     | Choice2Of2(e) -> return raise(e)
             }
     member x.Return(a) = async { return a }
     member x.ReturnFrom(a) = a    

 let workflow = WorkflowBuilder()
```

you can then compose simple async workflows yourself to get the desired result.

```
 let readHttp (uri:string) = 
       async { 
         let req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri)
         req.Method <- "GET"
         let! response = req.GetResponseAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
         let sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
         return sr.ReadToEnd()
      }

 let writeFile (path:string) (contents:string) = 
      async {
          let fs = File.OpenWrite(path)
          let sw = new StreamWriter(fs)
          do sw.Write(contents)
      }
```

Of course this implementation is language specific there is nothing really stopping a translation to C# or Java. The general design pattern being used here is a monad, put simply it is just some wrapping type (in this case Async<'a>) plus, two functions (bind and return), which you can see implemented in the WorkflowBuilder type.

I should mention some work will be required to productionize this code, but the idea is more important I feel.

Comment: Isn't the problem just composing of functions?
I mean, all readers take an Uri and return a thing
Then you transform the thing 
Then you save the thing.
i.e
getFromFile srcUri
|> transform
|> storeFtp destUri

Comment: Which is really all this does, but adds things like protecting the call..

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern, which allows you to compose a pipeline of objects that can act on a message.

In the chain of responsibility (one version of it), you have a `Handler` interface, and your individual behaviors implement that interface, and have a reference to the next handler. Pseudo-code, and probably not specific enough for your needs, but good for example:

```
interface Handler {
    protected Handler nextHandler;

    protected void pullData(string name);
    protected void pushData(string name, string data);

    public void process(string name);
}
```

So you would have an `HTTPHandler` implementing the interface:

```
class HTTPHandler implements Handler {
    public HTTPHandler(Handler nextHandler) {
        this.nextHandler = nextHandler;
    }

    protected void pullData(string name) {
        string data = getDataOverHTTP(name);
        if(!this.nextHandler == null) {
            this.nextHandler.pushData(name, data);
        }
    }

    protected void pushData(string name, string data) {
        postDataOverHTTP(name, data);
        if(!this.nextHandler == null) {
            this.nextHandler.pushData(name, data);
        }
    }

    public void process(string name) {
        this.pullData(name);
    }
}
```

Other classes can be built up accordingly, then composed together. Each `Handler` implementation knows to call the next handler in the list. And, the `Handler`s can be composed together dynamically at runtime. With one call to `process` on the first `Handler`, the data will be sent all the way down the pipeline. [This article](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern) details a fuller example of this way of chain of responsibility.

(FYI: An alternate way of doing this could be to create a collection that encapsulates a list of `Handler`s, and passes data between them using an intermediate data object.)